# Probability Statistics: Hyper-Geometric Distribution Tyre Manufacturing Question

Tags: probability

A room contains size-14 tyres as follows: 3 tyres manufactured by
Dunlop and 9 manufactured by Continental. Five tyres are
randomly selected from the room. What is the probability that
amongst the 5, there are at least 3 Continental tyres?

I assumed that once a tyre is randomly selected, it is not replaced, therefore the random variable X following a Hypergeometric Distribution with:

N= 9+3 = 12
K = 9
n = 5

When attempting to answer this problem, my idea to get P(X>=3) was by getting P(X<3) - by summing over the hypergeometric probability mass function from 0 to 2 - then subtracting whatever I get from 1. But when doing so, I ran into a computational error. For x = 0, N-K choose n-x gives me a math error in the numerator because N-K simplifies to 3 (12 - 9) and n-x simplifies to 5 (5 - 0). The error arises from not being able to take the factorial of a negative number (3-5)!, so basically my summation halts from the get-go. Could the be something wrong with my approach/thinking?

Comment: summing up is not necessary: $P(X<3)=P(X=2)$ in this case. $X$ cannot take any values less than $2$.

Comment: But isn't it also true that for P(X<3), P(X=1) also holds true, and likewise P(X=0)?

Comment: What do you mean by "...holds true"? In this case: $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=0$ simply because there are only $3$ tyres manufactured by Dunlop. $X=0$ and $X=1$ can only occur if there are *more* than $3$ tyres manufactured by Dunlop.

Comment: Oh, I now see what you mean. But the problem I have with your approach is the fact that if I only subtract the P(X=2) - where X is the random variable equal to the number of tyres in the sample that are from Continental - as you suggest, I will in actual fact be calculating the probability of there being EXACTLY three Continental tyres in the random selection of five tyres.  However, the problem is asking for the probability of there being AT LEAST three Continental tyres.

Comment: Meaning that there is a probability that there could be three Continental tyres in the selection, a different probability that there could be four, and as you'd expect, a different probability that all five tyres selected could be Continental tyres. Hence why I think a summation is required.......By the way, in my comment above, by ".... is the fact that if I only subtract the P(X=2)" I am referring to the subtraction of P(X=2) from one.

Comment: You *are* indeed calculating that *at least* $3$ continental tyres will be selected. This because in this context $1-P(X=2)=P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I finally see it now. I've just finished solving it. You've been of great help!